# Glade3 and changing strings within the GUI

Tags: user-interface, gtk, ada

I need GUI in which I have a number of strings regularly changing for instance in a multilanguage environment. So how can I enter these strings as variables instead as constants and still use the Gtkbuilder routine and be able to change the strings runtime. If that is impossible how can I tranlate the .glade file to an ADA file that doe the same.

**Edit**: I don't think the answer you gave me are real answers to my question, because I want the GUI changing languages without rebuilding the program, i.e. only one version of the program and not a version per language. Second point is that however I have not found then yet, but it can be possible that in other cases, it can be nice to have variables I can change during running the program instead of constants.

Answer (score 2):

- GtkAda https://www.AdaCore.com/gtkada should have a sufficiently complete coverage of the Gtk featureset for internationalization of strings https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/chapter-internationalization.html.en via POT & PO files as explained well https://www.drupal.org/community/contributor-guide/reference-information/localize-drupal-org/working-with-offline/po-and by the Drupal community for any UI that ultimately borrows from GNU gettext's leadership http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html on this POT & PO file approach to internationalization of strings.
- GtkAda has support
  https://docs.AdaCore.com/live/wave/gtkada/html/gtkada_ug/glade.html
  for Glade 3.
- Then gate3
  https://SourceForge.net/projects/lorenz/files should produce a GtkAda
  code sketch in Ada source code.

Comment: drupal guide is incorrect (though it can show how to use for germanic/romance languages) - following it goes wrong if you attempt to translate into slavic langauges. See example in https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps for re-creating a minimal example on Debian. I can't tell how portable this example actually is to other OS'es, but at least it's some starting point. Working with locales is not straight forward IMHO. Most of the mechanics in internationalization in GtkAda revolves around the package [gtkada-intl.ads](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada/blob/master/src/gtkada-intl.ads).

- First of all I enabled the locales of interest by running

  ```
  $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
  ```

  I wanted test translations for Dutch and French so I selected `fr_FR.UTF-8` and `nl_NL.UTF-8` in addition to those already selected (like, in my case, `en_US.UTF-8`). I also  kept `en_US.UTF-8` as the default locale. This was my locale configuration after the reconfiguration:

  ```
  $ locale -a
  C
  C.UTF-8
  en_US.utf8
  fr_FR.utf8
  nl_NL.utf8
  POSIX
  ```
- I then created a simple Glade UI file with a window (with title *"English"*) containing one label (with text *"Hello world!"*). I made sure that all the texts were marked "translatable". This is a property attribute that can be enabled via the "Edit Text" dialog box. This dialog box can be accessed by clicking the button on the right  side of the text area where you enter, for example, the label text.

  **example.glade** (note in particular the `translatable="yes"` attributes)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
  <interface>
     <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
     <object class="GtkWindow" id="Window">
       <property name="can_focus">False</property>
       <property name="title" translatable="yes">English</property>
       <property name="window_position">center</property>
       <property name="default_width">300</property>
       <property name="default_height">60</property>
       <child>
         <object class="GtkLabel" id="Label">
           <property name="visible">True</property>
           <property name="can_focus">False</property>
           <property name="label" translatable="yes">Hello world!</property>
         </object>
       </child>
     </object>
  </interface>
  ```
- I now created two translation files (`.po` files) as shown below: one for Dutch and one for French. Note how the `msgid` matches the window title text and label text.

  **translations_nl.po**

  ```
  msgid  "English"
  msgstr "Nederlands"

  msgid  "Hello world!"
  msgstr "Hallo wereld!"
  ```

  **translations_fr.po**

  ```
  msgid  "English"
  msgstr "Français"

  msgid  "Hello world!"
  msgstr "Bonjour le monde!"
  ```

  These files must be converted to machine readable files using the `msgfmt` tool that ships with GtkAda (see GtkAda's `bin` directory), i.e.

  ```
  $ msgfmt translations_nl.po -o messages.mo
  ```
- I finally created a project and the required Ada sources using GNAT Studio CE 2020 (sources are at the end of this answer). I made sure all files were organized as follows:

  ```
  example/
  +- example.glade
  +- default.gpr
  +- obj/
  |  +- <various build files>
  +- src/
  |  +- main.adb
  |  +- translation_demo.ads
  |  +- translation_demo.adb
  |  +- po/
  |     +- translations_nl.po
  |     +- translations_fr.po
  +- locales/
      +- nl_NL/
      |  +- LC_MESSAGES/
      |     +- messages.mo (generated using msgfmt)
      +- fr_FR/
         +- LC_MESSAGES/
            +- messages.mo (generated using msgfmt)
  ```

If all goes well, then after building and running the executable, the proper translations will appear in the UI depending on the setting of the [`LANGUAGE` environment variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Setting-the-POSIX-Locale.html#Setting-the-POSIX-Locale).

Note that in this example I set the `LANGUAGE` environment variable from within the program using the `Ada.Environment_Variables.Set` procedure (see `main.adb`). This is only to show how to control the language from within your program at application startup (e.g. in case you want to control the language via a configuration file read at startup; an approach that might be needed on OS'es other than Linux). On Debian (and Linux in general), the `LANGUAGE` environment variable is typically set by the OS on behalf of the user (check output of the `env` command).

As an alternative, you might also try the example without setting the environment variable in `main.adb` and check the result if you start the program via

```
LANGUAGE=nl_NL ./obj/main
```

or

```
LANGUAGE=fr_FR ./obj/main.adb
```

In conclusion, note that the process of getting this to work is a precise process: Debian must know the locales `nl_NL.UTF-8` and `fr_FR.UTF-8`, the `.mo` files must be available in the correct directories and the `LANGUAGE` environment variable must be set. Furthermore, because I use relative paths in the example code, the application must be started from project root directory, i.e.

```
$ ./obj/main
```

If something is wrong, then the translation will just not happen and no error and or warning will be provided.

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Environment_Variables;
with Translation_Demo;

procedure Main is
   
   NL : constant string := "nl_NL:nl";
   FR : constant String := "fr_FR:fr";
   
begin
   
   --  Set environment varianble.   
   Ada.Environment_Variables.Set ("LANGUAGE", NL);
   
   Translation_Demo.Run;
   
end Main;
```

**translation_demo.ads**

```
package Translation_Demo is

   procedure Run;

end Translation_Demo;
```

**translation_demo.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

with Gtk.Main;
with Gtk.Widget;
with Gtk.Builder;
with Gtk.Window;
with Gtk.Button;

with Gtkada.Intl;

with Glib;       use Glib;
with Glib.Error; use Glib.Error;

package body Translation_Demo is
   
   -- Name of the .mo file without extention.
   Text_Domain : constant String := "messages";        
   
   -- (Relative) location of the <lang>/LC_MESSAGES/<domain>.mo files.
   Text_Domain_Dir : constant String := "./locale";        
   
   -- (Relative) location of the Glade file.
   Glade_File : constant String := "./example.glade";

   
   Builder : Gtk.Builder.Gtk_Builder;
   Window  : Gtk.Window.Gtk_Window;


   procedure Destroy_Event_Callback
     (Widget : access Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record'Class);


   ---------
   -- Run --
   ---------

   procedure Run is

      use Gtk.Builder;
      use Gtk.Window;

      Success : GUint;
      Error   : aliased GError;

   begin      

      --  Initialize GtkAda.
      Gtk.Main.Init;

      --  Setup the translation domain and directory where to find the .mo files.
      Gtkada.Intl.Setlocale;
      Gtkada.Intl.Text_Domain (Text_Domain);
      Gtkada.Intl.Bind_Text_Domain (Text_Domain, Text_Domain_Dir);

      --  Construct a Gtk_Builder instance and load our UI description.
      Gtk_New (Builder);

      --  Set the translation domain for the Glade file.
      Builder.Set_Translation_Domain (Text_Domain);

      --  Read the Glade file.
      Success := Builder.Add_From_File (Glade_File, Error'Access);
      if Success = 0 then
         Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("failed to read Glade file");
         Error_Free (Error);
         Gtk.Main.Main_Quit;
      end if;

      --  Window
      Window := Gtk_Window (Builder.Get_Object ("Window"));
      Window.On_Destroy (Destroy_Event_Callback'Access);
      Window.Show_All;

      --  Start the main event loop
      Gtk.Main.Main;

   end Run;


   ----------------------------
   -- Destroy_Event_Callback --
   ----------------------------

   procedure Destroy_Event_Callback
     (Widget : access Gtk.Widget.Gtk_Widget_Record'Class)
   is
   begin
      Gtk.Main.Main_Quit;
   end Destroy_Event_Callback;

end Translation_Demo;
```

**default.gpr**

```
with "gtkada";

project Default is
   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Main use ("main.adb");
end Default;
```